# How do I exclude the stack trace from Elasticsearch's JSON logs

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logging, log4j

I want to find a way to remove the stack trace from the JSON output, especially on any log with a level less than error.

Currently the logs look like this:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00,000Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter", "cluster.name": "cluster", "node.name": "foo", "message": "unexpected error blah blah blah", "cluster.uuid": "CLUSTERID", "node.id": "NODEID" , "stacktrace": [ ... a bunch of stuff I don't really care about here ... ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using filebeats to ingest, you can specify a drop field:

```
processors:
 - drop_fields:
     fields: ["stacktrace"]
     ignore_missing: false
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/drop-fields.html

Comment: I mainly want to just trim down the disk space the logs themselves use.  Before I even ship them.

Comment: @TylerClendenin that's basically not an elasticsearch thing then. You can look at your logging framework options for retention and rolling though.